# Unable to set up Nginx to handle PHP along with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I have three requirements from my Nginx setup:

1. Forward all requests on / to my Java server running on port 9001
2. Intercept all static file URLs and serve them through Nginx itself.
3. Serve a particular base URL from a folder containing PHP scripts.

Of these, I'm able to achieve the first two, but when I visit `http://localhost/ecwid_fu_scripts/` through my web browser, the request is intercepted by the Java server running on port 9001, and doesn't get routed to the `index.php` in `/home/ankush/ecwid_fu_scripts/`. Here's my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location /assets/images/ {
        root /home/ankush/fu_main_files/;
        autoindex off;
        sendfile on; 
        tcp_nopush on; 
        tcp_nodelay on; 
        keepalive_timeout 100;
    }   

    location /ecwid_fu_scripts/ {
        index index.php;
        root /home/ankush/ecwid_fu_scripts/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }   

    location / { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
    }   

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is with the `root` directive, and the scope of this `root`.

```
location /ecwid_fu_scripts/ {
    root /home/ankush/ecwid_fu_scripts/;
```

In this case, when someone requests example.com/ecwid_fu_scripts/, nginx is looking for the files in the defined `root`, plus the location. This becomes /home/ankush/ecwid_fu_scripts/ecwid_fu_scripts/, which is not where your index.php is located.

To solve this, you have two choices (with #2 being the preferred option, if you have freedom over your project):

1. Change the `root` of that location block to /home/ankush/ instead.
2. **Or** restructure your project structure so everything is in one relative project folder. Now, set the global `root` -- the directive outside of any location block -- to the new project folder name (let's say `root /home/ankush/ecwid_files/;`, after the `server_name` directive).

Now, we still need to add the contents of the `location ~ \.php$` block inside the `location /ecwid_fu_scripts/` block, because when the `root` is changed, things relating to this new root needs to used in the same block. This is because of [this type of pitfall](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block): the location block for ecwid_fu_scripts is saying it's a .php file, it does try_files, and then it finishes with this block, and sent off to the next-related block: the global `location ~ \.php$`. Problem is, it doesn't know what the `root` is anymore, since it isn't defined globally. Thus, fastcgi_pass in this block isn't getting the full path.

So in the end, your config will look like this with option #1:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location /assets/images/ {
        root /home/ankush/fu_main_files/;
        autoindex off;
        sendfile on; 
        tcp_nopush on; 
        tcp_nodelay on; 
        keepalive_timeout 100;
    }   

    location /ecwid_fu_scripts/ {
        index index.php;
        root /home/ankush/;

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }   

    location / { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
    }   

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try that! Pardon my ignorance, but is the last block needed? What's its purpose? :-)

Comment: My new files looks like http://pastebin.com/5ZGN1EKE but now I'm getting 404 error on visiting `/ecwid_fu_scripts/`. I've double-checked that `/home/ankush/ecwid_fu_scripts/index.php` exists and file permissions are set to 775 and `www-data` is set as the owner and group of the directory. What could I be missing?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work and there's nothing in the error logs. There's just the 404 record in access logs. :'(

Comment: By the way, Nginx threw an error saying 'unknown variable path_info' so I deleted that line.

Comment: I got it working finally by adding another `root` directive to the main block. Not sure why it works this way. :\

Comment: @dotslash I am a bit slow today :) See this new config, I tested it myself and it worked http://pastebin.com/wnasKZM9 .. the mistake I made was that root issue: the try_files gets passed off to the "global" .php location. This location is not in ecwid_fu_scripts, since that root was never defined. So now your change worked because you defined that root, and so it hits that globally. So now this config should work, since it instead passes to FPM inside the same block. Will update answer in a bit!

Comment: Very nice! Can you tell me why we're doing `try_files $fastcgi_script_name` and not `try_files uri` inside the block? Sorry but I'm a total noob at this. I guess I need to read the entire Nginx manual. :P :-)

Comment: @dotslash I just copied those out of "[snippets/fastcgi-php.conf](http://pastebin.com/ayQuRwwn)" and removed comments to make it a bit lighter -- I don't know what distro you are using, so I didn't want to `include` the file if it didn't exist on yours. HTH!

Comment: Oh. Where are these snippets from? Your personal collection? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, BTW. I think I'll read up more on FastCGI and why these variables matter. For now, can you please update your answer so that I can accept it? :-)

Comment: They are automatically put there from the Ubuntu package; good that you're able to just `include` the file instead, makes it a bit cleaner looking. :)